# Is it possible to draw a rectangle in screen without a app/window?

Tags: python

I trying to draw a rectangle in the middle of the screen using python. However, I've only found solutions that create a GUI/Window and then show the object.
Here is an example of what I looking for

[Exemple](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aEVG8.png)

Comment: i'm gonna guess "no"

Comment: I think you need to create a frameless and transparent window, there are resources on how to do either one seperately but I didn't find any examples of both simultaniously, you will probably have to piece the two together youself...